# How to check the load time for submodules

Tags: selenium

I am running the script where One module having 20 submodules. My task is mousehover the main module and click the desired submodule, it may take few miliseconds to get load, I do have to calculate load time for each submodules. After clicking any of the module it does not change the URL, its just get loaded/open into iframe.
I tried with following code. But its giving the negative value. Also please let me know is this aright way to do so.

```
public void waitForLoading() throws InterruptedException
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(startTime);
        int count=0;
        while(loadingIcon.size()!=0 && count<10)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            count++;
        }
        long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(finishTime);
        long diff = startTime-finishTime;
        System.out.println(diff);
    }
```

The output of above code is startTime = 1619460610429 finishTime = 1619460635444 & Diff = -25015.
Can it be done with the help of TestNNG Listners?
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: You probably want to switch these around `diff = startTime-finishTime`, so `diff = finishTime - startTime`.

Comment: @SiKing, ohhh you are right. Is it right code? Can you please give some idea how can I implement TestNG listeners?

Comment: Above code can be used to to calculate load time for iframe?